# Wildcards in RegEx Haystack (target)?

Tags: regex

I want to search for a shorter string in a longer string.  Can the longer string (haystack/target) be setup with wildcards?

e.g.)  I want to look for 1234 in a string 1234578.  Sometimes the long string will be 1@345678 or 12@45678 due to I/O errors.  How do I setup the RegEx to match 1234 to 12345678 and any location of the @ symbol anywhere in the long string?

Reason: I have a scanner and it sometimes does not read one character correctly.  It replaces that character with a @ symbol.  How do I setup my RegEx so that I can have it ignore that @ character and match it?

Comment: @Toto  If I had 1@345678, and I remove it, it becomes 1345678 and will never match 1234.  I'm not sure how I can make it work that way.

Comment: You're right, I misread ;(

Answer (score 1):

Since I have programmatic control of the parsing process, I can programmatically modify the search string.

So instead of `/1234/`, it'll end up being `/(1|@)(2|@)(3|@)(4|@)/`

It's... really ugly, but that's my current solution.

The process isn't particularly difficult.  I'll use regex on the search string by using `/(.)/gm` and replace it with `($1|@)` so source `1234` becomes `(1|@)(2|@)(3|@)(4|@)` and search with that.

Comment: That way they can all be @ symbols. If you only want to match 1 @ out of 1-4, you could use an alternation like `(?:1234|@234|1@34|12@4|123@)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CFtblD/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Hmm, you got any idea on how to turn `1234` into `(?:1234|@234|1@34|12@4|123@)`?